# Experiences of using Neo4j with large datasets?

Tags: neo4j

Has anyone gone any experience of using Neo4j with terabyte sized datasets? I would like to hear about your expereinces with how Neo4j performs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as your disk is large and fast enough and your memory allows for caching of the relevant (hot) portion of your data, you shouldn't run into issues.

There are [optimizations](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Tuning_The_Neo4j_Native_Store) for tuning the Neo4j datastore to specific needs.

Otherwise it depends on the kind of your dataset. Query performance shouldn't be an issue, insert performance might suffer if you have to do a lot of index lookups for joining imported nodes (But the Neo4j team works on that).

Perhaps you should join the [Neo4j mailing list](https://lists.neo4j.org/mailman/listinfo/user) to answer all your questions more consistently.

Comment: Michael, do you mind joining me in this chat room (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33420/private-chat-enginefree). I have a couple questions on Neo4j. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We have been using Neo4j storing a graph of users and their relations with an approximate size now of 10 000 nodes and 400 000 relations,certain operations which are supported in a graph structure like getting friends of a user Neo4j is pretty fast.

It always depends on what queries you are going to run on the database and also the server machine storing your database.

Answer (score 4):

I use neo4j for handling the graph with 4 000 000 nides and 42 000 000 edges and it works great.

Have tried to find the shortest path between two random nodes and it took less than 100 ms. Retrieving the neighborhood of a neighbor, including friends, friends of friends and friends of friends of friends also takes almost no time while the relational database on same machine allows you to go for a lunch until it executes.

Comment: Hi @niko-namulin, I have also tried to store data in neo4j, but I am new bee in this field. I want to understand data modelling for social networking site. I have users with it's basic information like name, emailid, mobileno, address, city, country and friend list. I also need some feathers like graph search like facebook (user can search user, city, things), suggestion, friends request, recommendations etc. can you please give some hint for it? thanks